# How to clean an induction hob from scorching?

Tags: kitchens

After all water boiled, an empty teapot was left on the surface with turned on hob. You can see the spot on the photo. Is there some ways to fix or clean this?

Induction hob BOSCH PIB673F17E.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I must be getting old, or too much dust on my screen, because I'm not seeing the spot.

Comment: It is in the center of ring. You can see darken color than the hob itself. In the real it looks more contrast. So, the burnt spot is not very big, so I think it could be cleaned if it on the glass surface. Do you have any experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

We use Bon Ami to clean our cooktop and it removes everything. But you can buy other products specifically designed not to scratch like Soft Scrub.

Comment: Baking soda also works, and shouldn't scratch glass or ceramic.